# Android - изменить фон элемента в ListView

Tags: listview, android, java

По-умолчанию если нажать на элемент в ListView, то он окрасится голубым цветом. Я изменил цвет фона элемента через `View.setBackgroundColor(...)`, цвет изменился, но голубая окраска при нажатии пропала. Как её вернуть *без применения xml*?

Спросил здесь, так как не знаю, как сформулировать вопрос на английском для гугла)

Comment: Назначьте `view` в качестве фона `selector drawable` с нужными значениями для `default state` и `pressed state`.

Comment: А есть варианты попроще?

Comment: Разве этот сложный?

Comment: Често говоря, для меня - да. Я думал, что можно всё будет сделать одной/двумя строками java кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант для ленивых (сам иногда пользуюсь) [holo-colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/)  качаете List Selector и меняете нужные места как сказал [[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)  (можно взять из исходников, но мне так удобнее)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю полезно будет изучить вот эту [статью](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/08/08/listview-tips-tricks-3-create-fancy-listviews/).